# How to redirect already logged on user who is trying to access Logon page MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

I'm using MVC3 with form authentication. Everything work fine except one thing. I want to redirect authenticated user to another page when he/she tries to access LogOn page again. So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your LogOn Action do something like this.

```
if (HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
}

return View();
```

Comment: It's `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated`. Thank for your help, Sir!